# how to set cookies and delete cookies everytime i make a new query in this code

Tags: php, cookies

```
 <?php
     if ($id) 
    {   
     if (empty($_COOKIE['id'])) {
     setcookie('id', $id, strtotime("+2 years"), '/');
}   
    $db->select("username", "member", "username='$id' and status=1");
        if($db->num_rows() > 0) {
        $sponsor=$db->result(0, "username");
        $ref = $sponsor;
    } 
    else {
        $db->select("username", "member", "status=1 and paket=1", "rand()", 1);
        $ref=$db->result(0, "username");
        header("location:?id=$ref");    
          } 

    } else {
        $db->select("username", "member", "status=1 and paket=1", "rand()", 1);
        $sponsor=$db->result(0, "username");
        $ref=$sponsor;
        header("location:?id=$ref");
    }
    ?>
```

that codes above is my affiliate scripts to set cookies to that affiliate id, how can i set a new cookie everytime user click a new link example www.domain.com/?id=user1 and then all the id & cookies is set to user1, and a user click a new link www.domain.com/?id=user2 at same computer, how to make the link will go to www.domain.com/?id=user1 not user2 ? (because the cookies user1 is exist)

can i set the cookies available to 2 years, if the computer user delete the cookies at his browser?

can someone help how to make this script work with cookies

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial cookie using PHP setcookie();

```
setcookie('affiliateid', $id, strtotime("+2 years"), '/');
```

That will most likely go into your first IF statement.

Then, to check if a cookie exists so that you don't overwrite it, just use the global $_COOKIE variable/Array.

```
if (empty($_COOKIE['affiliateid'])) {
    //use the setcookie() code here since the cookie doesn't exist
}
```

Btw... you have 2 ELSE statements in your code, that isn't right, the 2nd ELSE statement will never be used or it'll throw a warning I guess.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: im using this 
<?php if ($id) 

{  
        if (empty($_COOKIE['id'])) {

 setcookie('id', $id, strtotime("+2 years"), '/');
} $db->select("username", "member", "username='$id' and status=1");

the cookies already set.. example : the cookies id is=andy but when i go to www.domain.com/?id=andry it doesnt refer to www.domain.com/?id=andy ? how should i do